# Is it possible to still get updates on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, updates, support

Is it possible to still get updates on Ubuntu 12.04 in 2018? Cause my PC loved the Ubuntu 12.04 and I loved it.

So is it possible, or not? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to still get ongoing (security only) updates to 12.04 is to enroll in the Ubuntu Advantage program for your 12.04 boxes.  (There are minimum numbers of "licenses" you have to purchase, however, which means you need to be willing to pay a lot for these services).

This is the only way to get the Extended Security Maintenance for 12.04.  Details [can be found on Canonical's site](https://buy.ubuntu.com/).

Without Ubuntu Advantage, you will not get 12.04 ESM updates.  (However, 12.04 questions will remain offtopic here on Ask Ubuntu - ESM is a Canonical offering, so support will have to come from them)

In many cases, you're probably just going to want to upgrade rather than pay for the support, as in some cases the cost is prohibitively expensive.

Comment: So  should I pay for get more updates?

Comment: @BalázsVámos That's the only way, yes, and it'd only get you security updates.  The other no-cost option is to just upgrade to a newer supported release.

Comment: @BalázsVámos 12.04 went End of Life back in 2017, and is old enough that ongoing support for it is very difficult for newer software and such, it's one of the reasons it went End of Life.  ESM is the only way to get ongoing support and security-only updates, and it's *not* cheap unfortunately.

Comment: Yap it went unfortunately. I loved ubuntu 10 and 12.04. So sad I cant use ubuntu 12 rolling.